# Two classes that differ only with template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to create two template classes with the same name, that only differ in the number of template parameters? For example,

```
template<typename T>
struct Tuple {
    T Item;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct Tuple {
    T1 Item1;
    T2 Item2;
};
```

Comment: it would be quicker to just try it rather than ask it here.

Comment: You can see how `std::tuple` implemented.

Comment: it is even possible to define the template with variadic number of parameters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

Comment: @RichardHodges: I did, of course, and since it didn't work, I asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with the syntax you used, but there are alternative solutions:

#### Option #1:

*(C++03)*

```
template <typename T1, typename T2 = void>
struct Tuple
{
    T1 Item1;
    T2 Item2;
};

template <typename T1>
struct Tuple<T1, void>
{
    T1 Item;
};
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76e51eb0a48f5a06)

#### Option #2:

*(C++11)*

```
template <typename...>
struct Tuple;

template <typename T1>
struct Tuple<T1>
{
    T1 Item;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    T1 Item1;
    T2 Item2;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce3cc992215bffe3)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. What you're looking for is something like `class templates overloading`. According to `Exceptional C++ Style Chapter 7`:

> In C++, there are class templates and function templates. These two
>   kinds of templates don't work in exactly the same ways, and the most
>   obvious difference is in overloading: Plain old C++ classes don't
>   overload, so class templates don't overload either. On the other hand,
>   plain old C++ functions having the same name do overload, so function
>   templates are allowed to overload too. This is pretty natural.

Basiclly, you can achieve the functionality by `partially specialization`. Such as:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2 = T1>
struct Tuple {
    T1 Item1;
    T2 Item2;
};
template<typename T>
struct Tuple<T, T> {
    T Item;
};
```

And then

```
Tuple<int, long> t1;  // use main template
Tuple<float> t2;      // use specialized template
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/I28Mqg)

Comment: The specialization with `void` seems better than your as it seems more intuitive to have 2 fields with `Tuple<int, int>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, at least, not that way.

But you should consider variadic templates …

Here is a basic tuple example (stolen form http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/):

```
template <class... Ts> struct tuple {};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> {
  tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), tail(t) {}

  T tail;
};
```